# Debug interface for code wrapped in requireJs

Tags: javascript, jquery, requirejs

I've got a javascript program `apps.js` which is loaded in my `index.html` file like this:

```
<script data-main='apps.js' src='js/require.js'></script>
```

where `apps.js` is auto-generated code, but includes a requirejs module. I would like to configure a `test.html` which loads a `test.js` file after `apps.js` is loaded. The purpose is that `test.js` lets me quickly test specific components from `apps.js`, so I want to treat `apps.js` as a standalone library.

What are my options?

One option I've found is for `test.html` to only load `test.js` in a `data-main` line, and then `test.js` to use something like this at its top:

```
$.ajaxSetup({async:false});
$.getScript("apps.js");
$.ajaxSetup({async:true});
```

but I'm not sure that's the best approach. Any other ideas? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just require your app.js file, assuming your return a definition of something. Your test.js would have code like this:

```
require(['app'], function(app) {

// You can now test stuff on app here.
assert(app.myFunction()).equals(1); // Will be true.

});
```

Your app.js file probably has contents like this:

```
require(function() {

 var myApp = {
    myFunction: function() {
     return 1;
    }
 };

return myApp;

});
```

Comment: `apps.js` doesn't return anything, and I didn't need to alter it. i.e. i just ignore the argument to the function in `test.js`.